# File writing in Robocode (Java)

Tags: java, file, robocode

Basically, I am trying to generate a log file in Robocode, but I am having issues as you cannot use try/catch in Robocode (as far as I am aware). I have done the following:

```
public void onBattleEnded(BattleEndedEvent e) throws IOException
{
    writeToLog();
    throw new IOException();
}
```

and

```
public void writeToLog() throws IOException
{
    //Create a new RobocodeFileWriter.
    RobocodeFileWriter fileWriter = new RobocodeFileWriter("./logs/test.txt");
    for (String line : outputLog)
    {
        fileWriter.write(line);
        fileWriter.write(System.getProperty("line.seperator"));
    }
    throw new IOException();
}
```

and am getting the following error at compile time:-

```
MyRobot.java:123: onBattleEnded(robocode.BattleEndedEvent) in ma001jh.MyRobot cannot implement onBattleEnded(robocode.BattleEndedEvent) in robocode.robotinterfaces.IBasicEvents2; overridden method does not throw java.io.IOException
    public void onBattleEnded(BattleEndedEvent e) throws IOException
                ^
1 error
```

Comment: I would like to see the interface too. Have you imported `java.io.IOException` only and not something else?

Comment: Yeah, I have imported that only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see [here](http://robocode.sourceforge.net/docs/robocode/robocode/robotinterfaces/IBasicEvents2.html#onBattleEnded%28robocode.BattleEndedEvent%29), the interface doesn't declare any checked exceptions. So you can't throw one in your implementing class.

One way to solve this would be to implement your method like this:

```
public void onBattleEnded(BattleEndedEvent e)
{
    writeToLog();   
    throw new RuntimeException(new IOException());
}

public void writeToLog()
{
    //Create a new RobocodeFileWriter.      
    RobocodeFileWriter fileWriter = new RobocodeFileWriter("./logs/test.txt");
    for (String line : outputLog)
    {
        fileWriter.write(line);
        fileWriter.write(System.getProperty("line.seperator"));
    }       
    throw new new RuntimeException(new IOException());
}
```

Comment: See therein is the problem; if I take it away, the compiler then gives an error saying basically that the Exception must be caught or declared.

Comment: Then declare as `throws RuntimeException`

Comment: Thanks, as you can probably tell I am relatively new to Java, and very new to Exception Handling. Anyway, so I declared as `throws RuntimeException`, and the compiler still wants me to catch or declare the `IOException`. I tried to use `throw new RuntimeException`, but that wouldn't work. Thanks.

Comment: Can you please show me the contents of the interface? I feel I'm missing something important.

Comment: Sorry, what exactly do you mean by that. Sorry, I am new to this whole Java thing. Thanks.

Comment: I mean, is [this](http://robocode.sourceforge.net/docs/robocode/robocode/robotinterfaces/IBasicEvents2.html) the interface you have implemented in MyRobot.java?

Comment: I have used the method in there yes, how would I "implement" it? Sorry, I know this must be tedious.

Answer (score 1):

> but I am having issues as you cannot use try/catch in Robocode (as far as I am aware)

Where did this assumption came from? I just because of your question here installed robocode (so it's your fault if I'll answer here less often in future), wrote my own robot and it can catch exceptions quite good:

```
try {
   int i = 1/0;
}
catch(ArithmeticException ex) {
   ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

And why are you throwing IOExceptions in your example?

Comment: Yeah, sorry I got a little confused with the limits robocode places with regards to exception handling. I tried that as part of a trial/error scenario. I am after all a new CS student, mistakes have to be made.